# TeamCity - Cucumber Acceptance Tests failing during day but passing in overnight build

Tags: cucumber, teamcity, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

We're testing a web app using Cucumber and the PageObject gem, running CI on TeamCity. We've hit on a problem that none of us can solve.

We're accessing two drop-downs whose combined contents generate a field of radio selections. When I run this from my local machine, it passes but when run from the integration server against the same environment, it fails most of the time...

...except at night. I configured some scheduled builds so I could observe it in a stable environment and it consistently passes overnight.

The error it throws is that the country drop-down (the second field, dependent on 'client', which is the first) doesn't contain the value for selection. I've examined it manually and it appears that the Client box is empty.

The automation code giving rise to the error is below. Please note that I've tried several methods to access this including dropping down to Watir Webdriver but none have made any difference.

DO you think this is just a simple performance issue? I don't see how it can be because the test agents only run one project at a time so theoretically they should perform the same regardless of build load.

```
def safe_select_client(value, attempts = 10)

  count_attempts_to(attempts)do
    self.client_code = value
    if self.client_code_element.selected? value
      next
    else
      $stdout.puts attempts-1
      safe_select_client(value, attempts-1)
    end
  end
end

def safe_select_country(value, attempts = 10)
  count_attempts_to(attempts) do
    self.client_country = value
    if self.client_country_element.selected? value
      next
    else
      safe_select_country(value, attempts-1) unless self.client_country_element.selected? value
    end
  end
end


def safe_select_proposition(value, attempts = 10)
  count_attempts_to(attempts) do
    self.select_default_proposition
    safe_select_proposition(value, attempts-1) unless default_proposition_selected?
  end
end
```

Comment: Looking at the code above it seems like you are setting the value on the drop down and then immediately checking to see if the value was set.  Why are you doing this?  What caused you to write this code?

Comment: Because the value wasn't being reliably set in the element. I'd end up with stalled scripts because the dependent select_lists weren't being populated. I could never reproduce this manually but saw it in the automated suite all the time.

Comment: That should probably be 'delayed' scripts, because obviously they'd report an error and move on after timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for this.

The app developers looked into this and discovered that the bug was related to application robustness, not test code: the client was caching the values for the drop-downs. It's bug which would never have been uncovered - or would have been discovered in production, with a far costlier fix - if it weren't for automated acceptance testing.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a performance issue in that the script is trying to set the country dropdown before it has finished loading.

Without knowing what the `count_attempts_to` method does, it looks like your code attempts to set the dropdown value and re-attempt it many times. However, if the value does not exist, the re-tries probably do not get run since an exception would already have been thrown. Even if the retry portion worked, the retries appear immediate, so the dropdown may still not have loaded.

You should likely be using the built in waiting methods instead - see http://watirwebdriver.com/waiting/.

Assuming that `count_attempts_to` is just part of your retry mechanism, I think you could rewrite the country method (and the others) like:

```
def safe_select_country(value)
  self.client_country_element.option(:value => value).when_present.set
end
```

This says wait for the option for up to 30 seconds. When it is found, select it.

Comment: I've tried that, I'm afraid. It actually impaired the robustness of the scripts because I then started seeing StaleElementReferenceErrors in addition to my existing problems.

Comment: Did the exception tell you which element was stale - the client_country select list or the option value?

Comment: I'm looking for the error but TeamCity logs aren;t easy to search

Comment: I've given this some thought: it wouldn't throw a StaleElementReferenceError if it couldn't find a value, would it?

Comment: It seems less likely, but it is possible for a StaleElementReferenceError to occur. For example, maybe the script gets the client country dropdown, to populate the dropdown perhaps the application deletes the entire dropdown and rebuilds it, then the script tries to access the now stale dropdown. But yes, it seems unlikely. I would suggest trying to run this code again and see what the exception is. With that, it would give us more information to debug/address the problem.